# Conditional formatting with subtraction

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am currently trying to calculate two results with one formula, to check whether the result is greater or less than 18

If it is larger than 18, the line should be colored red, if smaller then green.

I have already tried the formula "indirectly", but this cannot be transferred to other cells, because I want to copy it down to other cells.

Then I tried the formula "Index", but with this formula, I don't get an error, but also not the solution of the problem.

example of a formula what I have used, what isn't a solution

```
=index('Data Sheet1'!B2)-index('Data Sheet!'!C2)>18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a sheet with name **Sheet51** looks like this:

[image: 0]

then in another sheet/tab, you can do this:

- for red 


  ```
  =AND(LEN(INDIRECT("Sheet51!A1:A")), 
   IF(INDIRECT("Sheet51!A1:A")-INDIRECT("Sheet51!B1:B")<18, 1))
  ```
- for green


  ```
  =AND(LEN(INDIRECT("Sheet51!A1:A")),
   IF(INDIRECT("Sheet51!A1:A")-INDIRECT("Sheet51!B1:B")>=18, 1))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, though, I'd appreciate it if you added links to relevant documentation for further reading on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting for this. First apply **minus()** formula to the cell and then apply conditional formatting (Format->Conditional Formatting) to apply rules on the whole column [If it is larger than 18, the line should be colored red, if smaller then green.]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.

But how to use this, if the data are in another / different sheets?